# Cite another publication in bibliography item

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to refer to another reference in a bibliography item. It should look like the following in the bibliography:

```
[30] Author (Year), Cited in [12].
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! You can use a regular `\cite` command in the `note` field e.g. `note = {Cited in \cite{bibkey}.}`